# How does caste relate to Hinduism in practice?

Tags: caste-system

To my understanding in the most ancient times, caste was a label based on profession. My question is, did it have any influence on how Hinduism was practiced?

For example, Would Hinduism, in practices (devotion methods, prayers, etc), be the same for a brahmin and a shudra?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Really? Could you be more specific how it falls off